# how to set a style for single words in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to insert single words with a specific style in a word document from a macro. Whenever I change the Style property of the Selection object or even of a range (e.g. ActiveDocument.Range(1,3)) the style of the whole paragraph is set.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to apply a paragraph style.
These styles can only be applied to complete paragraphs.

If you apply a character style, it will work fine.

Comment: it kind of works, but still not completly, I have a problem with resetting it then. I tried
`    Selection.Style = "Fett"
    Selection.TypeText "test"
    Selection.Style = "Standard"
    Selection.TypeText "gwe"
but then the whole text is bold("Fett" is german for bold)

Comment: @DaVinci: Set it to `Default Paragraph Font`.

Comment: I suppose the "Standard" style is the german "Default Paragraph Font".
I also tried `    Dim prevStyle As String  
    prevStyle = Selection.Style  
    Selection.Style = "Fett"  
    Selection.TypeText "test"  
    Selection.Style = prevStyle  
    Selection.TypeText "gwe"`

Comment: @DaVinci: You need to check `CharacterStyle`.

Comment: @SLaks there is no CharacterStyle property in Selection, what do you mean?
edit: Font.reset seams to work.

Comment: @DaVinci: Check `Selection.Range.CharacterStyle.NameLocal`

Answer (score -2):

You can simply select the word with your mouse (click&drag with the cursor) and then select the text properties such as the font, only the selected characters will change to that font.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to do it manually for each word, I think they want a way for it to apply automatically for certain words, for the entire document.